# Prove $(x^2-2)\sin(x)+2x\cos(x)\geq 0$ for $x$ on $[0,\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Originally comes from the question
[How to prove $\dfrac{\sin(A)}{A} +\dfrac{\sin(B)}{B}+\dfrac{\sin(C)}{C}< \dfrac{9*3^{0.5}}{2\pi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998624/how-to-prove-sina-asinb-bsinc-c93-5-2pi).

The goal is proving $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ concave down on $[0,\pi/2)$, which I find it non-trivial.

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus, or do you want an elementary (i.e. non-calculus) solution?

Comment: No restriction on how to do it as long as it's mathematically rigorous.

Comment: Then just note that it's continuous (and can be differentiated twice) on that interval, and find the second-derivative, no? (I haven't tried this yet, so I don't know if it's messy.)

Comment: Second derivative of $sin(x)/x$ is $-((x^2-2)sin(x)+2xcos(x))/x^3$, which is where this question comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a logical approach.

Take $f(x) = (x^2 - 2)\sin(x)$ and $g(x) = -2x\cos(x)$

If $x^2\sin(x) - 2\sin(x) + 2\cos(x) \ge 0$ is true then,

$x^2\sin(x) - 2\sin(x) \ge -2\cos(x)$ must also suffice (be true). Which means

$f(x) \ge g(x)$

Now:

$f(0) = 0$ and $g(0) = 0$ therefore $f(0) = g(0)$ Now, take the respective first derivatives.

$f'(x) = x^2\cos(x) + 2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x)$

$g'(x) = 2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x)$

$f'(x) \ge g'(x)$ is the assumption we will use.

$x^2\cos(x) + 2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x) \ge 2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x)$

Add $-2\cos(x)$ and subtract $2x\sin(x)$ to/from both sides. You are left with

$x^2\cos(x) \ge 0$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$

Which is a true inequality, therefore $f'(x) > g'(x)$ on $(0, \pi/2)$ is true.

Since $f(0) = g(0)$, and we know that $f'(x) > g'(x)$ on $(0, \pi/2)$ this means $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ which means $f(x) > g(x) \implies f(x) - g(x) > 0$

$\implies (x^2 - 2)\sin(x) + 2x\cos(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, \pi/2)$

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides of the inequality by $\cos x$ and use the inequality $\tan x>x$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2 - 2)x + 2x \geq 0 \Rightarrow (x^2 - 2)\tan x + 2x \geq 0 \Rightarrow \ \cdots$

Comment: And I see that Subham has just written the same thing.